# How to know which index used by the SELECT in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

The table has many different indexes, and some indexes share one field. I want to know which index used in a select query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem. Just issue your SELECT with EXPLAIN prepended. Like this:

```
explain select field1, field2 from table1
```